# Uno Ethernet shield and TMP36 reading

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, analogread

I am just getting started with my Uno via the Vilros Ultimate Starter Kit. I've done all of the sample circuits and played around with a few other things.

Today I connected the Ethernet shield with the intention of building a temperature logger. I am finding that the output I get from the included TMP36 temperature sensor is much different with the Ethernet shield installed.

The kit's sample circuit #7 for the temperature sensor connects the sensor directly to 5V and GND and the sensor output to A0. The loop code (compressed a bit for pasting here) looks like this:

```cpp
float voltage, degreesC, degreesF;
voltage = analogRead(temperaturePin) * 0.004882814;
degreesC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100.0;
degreesF = degreesC * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0;
// Write to serial; omitting for brevity
delay(1000);
```

*Without* the Ethernet shield installed, a typical output I get from this looks like:

```cpp
voltage: 0.81  deg C: 30.57  deg F: 87.02
```

That might be a little high but it feels close enough for what I'm going for at the moment (I don't have a reliable thermometer with me, but it's a warm day here). It's close enough, and is stable across readings.

*With* the shield installed, the exact same circuit and sketch outputs this:

```cpp
voltage: 0.96  deg C: 46.19  deg F: 115.14
```

It's still very stable across readings but obviously way off. What could cause this and how can I fix it? I am not expecting the sensor to be perfectly accurate but the major discrepancy I'm seeing makes this unworkable.

Comment: Well, three years later I have the same problem. Did you eventually find a solution?